# AVR SBI for SPI Ports H+ atmega2560

Tags: assembly, avr, spi, atmega

I'm am not that strong in avr/assembly and I'm having problems selecting "CS" from PORTH on atmega2560 ... can you help me?

the code:

```
#define DDR_CS  _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRH), 5   // MMC CS pin (DDR, PORT)
#define PORT_CS _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTH), 5

#define DDR_CK  _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB), 1   // MMC SCLK pin (DDR, PORT)
#define PORT_CK _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB), 1

#define DDR_DI  _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB), 2   // MMC DI pin (DDR, PORT)
#define PORT_DI _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB), 2

#define PIN_DO  _SFR_IO_ADDR(PINB), 3   // MMC DO pin (PIN, PORT)
#define PORT_DO _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB), 3



;---------------------------------------------------------------------------;
.nolist
#include <avr/io.h>
.list
.text


;---------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; Initialize MMC port
;
; void init_spi (void);

.global init_spi
.func init_spi
init_spi:
     sbi    DDR_CS      ; CS: output
     sbi    DDR_DI      ; DI: output
     sbi    DDR_CK      ; SCLK: output
     sbi    PORT_DO     ; DO: pull-up
     ret
.endfunc
```

The error that I'm geting:

> asmfunc.S:44: Error: number must be positive and less than 32

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27477833/7210049) and I think this is the answer bat I don't know how to write it in the correct syntax.

Comment: The direct bit manipulation instructions are limited to certain ports. You will need to manually read-modify-write the bit yourself instead (something along the lines of `IN Rx,PORTH + ORI Rx,0x20 + OUT PORTH,Rx`). Take care with interrupt races hwoever since the sequence is no longer atomic. In any event, I would also suggest consider switching to a higher level language which you may be more comfortable developing in.